# How to prevent users from entering a comma in an input with regex validation?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a regex that allows only a number or dot. Commas should be forbidden.

```
<input validator="/^\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$/" maxlength="11" validator-invoke="watch"
```

[image]

[image]

This shows an error as expected, but what I actually want to achieve is to not even allow the user to enter a comma, or automatically delete the comma if the former is not possible.

I would like to implement this in either AngularJS, HTML, or vanilla JavaScript, but it needs to work for IE.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You need to double escape those backslashes, because you have a *string* and they would be first parsed as string escape sequences

Comment: @VLAZ it is a html attribute, so it is parsed as such, and there the escape sequence does not start with ``\``  but with `&`. And based on the question the `validator` itself works.

Comment: Not allowing certain characters to be written can be quiet annoying and may lead to more errors than preventing. E.g. if someone is about to write `102.34` and instead writes `102,34`, then this would result in `10234` which would be valid, but the error might easier overlook as it is not becoming red. A better solution is showing an error like you already do, or probably replacing the `,` by a `. `while writing.

Comment: To be clear, you said AngularJS, but do you mean AngularJS or Angular?

Answer (score -2):

This can solve the issue to not include any comma value into text box.

```
<input type="number"/>
```

Comment: This would not allow a period and also wouldn't prevent someone from typing in it with whatever content they want (e.g. the scenario he already has).